# Where do Poco and Boost overlap?

Tags: c++, boost, libraries, compatibility, poco

I have no experience with the [Poco libraries](https://pocoproject.org/), but some experience with Boost. From a brief look at the Poco documentation, it seems they document the higher-level functionality they offer more than abstract fundamentals, language-augmenting facilities. For example: Boost touts a library of iterators, a library of integer-type-related facilities etc.

Other than extensively browsing the Poco sources - how can I determine what's the overlap of the functionality and facilities offered by Poco and by Boost?

Notes:

- I'm not asking about pros and cons - which are relevant to the overlap part - but rather for an identification of the overlap vs the "symmetric difference" in what they offer. It seems like there there might be less overlap than you would expect given that some people present Poco and Boost as alternatives to each other.
- If Poco provides something as an "internal" utility, but which is usable by whoever uses Poco, I would still count that in the overlap.

Comment: I did some searching, I didn't find a good comparison that discussed the overlap and/or differences.  (And the twisty link-chain alley ended up comparing against Perforce RogueWave, of all things.)  (I did not downvote.)